# How to mint multiple cNFTs?

Tags: metaplex, cnft, bubblegum

I'm using this fonction to mint a cNFT `createMintToCollectionV1Instruction` but I don't want to wait 5-10sec before minting an other cNFT.
Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to wait to mint additional cNFTs, any rate limiting you're experiencing probably has to do with the RPC server you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This was only on local net to test program that would interface with cNFTs, but I had this utility function that I invoked at the beginning of each test suite.

```
export async function setupTreeWithCompressedNFT(
  connection: Connection,
  payerKeypair: Keypair,
  compressedNFT: MetadataArgs,
  depthSizePair: ValidDepthSizePair = {
    maxDepth: 14,
    maxBufferSize: 64,
  }
): Promise<{
  merkleTree: PublicKey;
}> {
  const payer = payerKeypair.publicKey;

  const merkleTreeKeypair = Keypair.generate();
  const merkleTree = merkleTreeKeypair.publicKey;
  const space = getConcurrentMerkleTreeAccountSize(
    depthSizePair.maxDepth,
    depthSizePair.maxBufferSize
  );
  const allocTreeIx = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: payer,
    newAccountPubkey: merkleTree,
    lamports: await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(space),
    space: space,
    programId: SPL_ACCOUNT_COMPRESSION_PROGRAM_ID,
  });
  const [treeAuthority, _bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
    [merkleTree.toBuffer()],
    BUBBLEGUM_PROGRAM_ID
  );
  const createTreeIx = createCreateTreeInstruction(
    {
      merkleTree,
      treeAuthority,
      treeCreator: payer,
      payer,
      logWrapper: SPL_NOOP_PROGRAM_ID,
      compressionProgram: SPL_ACCOUNT_COMPRESSION_PROGRAM_ID,
    },
    {
      maxBufferSize: depthSizePair.maxBufferSize,
      maxDepth: depthSizePair.maxDepth,
      public: false,
    },
    BUBBLEGUM_PROGRAM_ID
  );

  const mintIx = createMintV1Instruction(
    {
      merkleTree,
      treeAuthority,
      treeDelegate: payer,
      payer,
      leafDelegate: payer,
      leafOwner: payer,
      compressionProgram: SPL_ACCOUNT_COMPRESSION_PROGRAM_ID,
      logWrapper: SPL_NOOP_PROGRAM_ID,
    },
    {
      message: compressedNFT,
    }
  );

  const tx = new Transaction().add(allocTreeIx).add(createTreeIx).add(mintIx);
  tx.feePayer = payer;
  await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    tx,
    [merkleTreeKeypair, payerKeypair],
    {
      commitment: "confirmed",
      skipPreflight: true,
    }
  );

  return {
    merkleTree,
  };
}
```